# apache - Can't upload >2GB file

Tags: apache, upload, limit

Uploading files in our app works fine until we hit one that's > 2GB.

error_log shows:

```
Invalid Content-Length
(-3)Unknown error: Error reading request entity data
```

I've rebuilt the latest apache 64bit with large file support and I still get this error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you might be running into this http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm
2gb seems to be a hard limit in many browsers.